# How to put \hyperdef{category}{name}{} at the same position as \label{name}?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

I am using the `hyperref` package that comes without the `destlabel` option (I tried to use the most recent version of `hyperref`, but it doesn't work with my LaTeX version).

So to be able to create named destinations in my PDF whose names are fixed, I use `\hyperdef{cat}{name}{}`. However, it is placed at a different location than a corresponding `\label{name}`. The following illustrates my problem

```
\subsection{General Introduction}
\label{foo}\hyperdef{bar}{foo}{}
```

The end result I get is (sorry for the ASCII art)

```
{Here is the \label destination in the PDF}
7.9.5 General Introduction
{Here is the \hyperdef destination in the PDF}
```

I would like to have the `\hyperdef` to be at the position that the `\label` takes. How can I make this happen?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

You could use option `destlabel` of `hyperref` 2012/07/28 v6.82u or later. Then `hyperref` uses the first label name for the anchor name and you would not need an additional `\hyperdef`.

Comment: The OP stated that he uses an older version of `hyperref`. (Maybe the "correct" answer is that he should upgrade or install the current version locally.)

Comment: i tried that. See my initial note "I am using the hyperref package that comes without the destlabel option (I tried to use the most recent version of hyperref, but it doesn't work with my LaTeX version)" :) I am really lost :/

Comment: I wonder whether i could just apply a patch that just adds "destlabel" without anything else?

Comment: If you want to have a feature that an older version does not provide, but a newer version supports, then update.

Comment: hmm fair game. i guess i have to go that route :(

Answer (score 1):

[pandoc](/questions/tagged/pandoc) does it like this:

```
\hyperdef{bar}{foo}{\subsection{General introduction}}\label{bar}
```